# Is there a way to upload a folder to GitHub with more than 100 files?

Tags: github

I have a folder with more than 100 files I would like to upload to GitHub because I am working on a project with a few people. I am trying to create a repo and than upload the 5,000+ files folder to it.

Comment: Have you had a specific problem doing that? 100 isn't very many files.

Comment: One: It's a couple thousand, 2: You can't upload more than 100 at a time and I want a quick way to do it

Comment: *"You can't upload more than 100 at a time"* - what do you mean "upload"? Are you trying to push a commit, or something else? Put a [mre] in the question.